# Why does Facebook Album always return empty while I using new facebook app id?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a facebook app Id for my iOS app and configured in .Plist it always return empty dictionary.But if I configure my old facebook app Id which I created 6 months ago, it returns the albums.I confused with this thing whether facebook restricted to get the facebook albums or whichever is wrong with this process. I stuck with this issue from yesterday .please anybody help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The user you're testing with needs to give the new app the `user_photos` permission, otherwise you'll not be able to retrieve his photos on his behalf.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/albums#readperms